# Scaleout in SignalR (share server connection)

Tags: connection, signalr

I found some topics on MSDN about [SignalR scaleout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr).
But these approaches don't fit me.
I have a windows app that host a SignalR server. But I should find a way to share the server connection between many application on the same PC because this app uses on terminal server and each client should have his own app with own server, but use the same port.

Some code:

```cs
using (SignalRConnection connection = new SignalRConnection("https://localhost:9090"))
{
     Application.Run();
}

public class SignalRConnection : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }

    public SignalRConnection(string serverURI)
    {
        SignalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>(serverURI);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SignalR.Dispose();
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration()
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJSONP = true
        });

        var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
        listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
    }
}
```